# C# Self Installing windows service

Tags: c#

I Just want to create a program to say hello message via Form1 after every reboot. I know i can do that with registery key (CurrentVersion\Run) but i need to do that with services for learning that section.

I made my Form1 like this

[image]
And i tried to self install via command prompt like this

[image]
and i adjusted to program.cs like this

[image]
but when i rebuilted and compailed it this error occur

> Cannot start service from the command line or debugger. A winwows Service must first be installed(using installutil.exe) and then started with the ServerExplorer, Windows Services Afministrative tool or the NET START command.

so where should i fix ?

Comment: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)

Comment: Services cannot interact with the desktop in (IIRC) Vista or later. Because what happens when the service starts before anyone has logged in?

Comment: Form and WindowsServices "do not get a long" (kind of.. think about Windows services as background processes without UI) so the better approach is to initiate "external" process outside of the service to do the welcoming greet for you. Also checkout the comment of @JohnnyMopp

Comment: Use TopShelf http://topshelf-project.com/

Comment: [I downvoted because being unresponsive to comments is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/beingunresponsive), and because [images of code are not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode).

Answer (score 2):

For debugging Windows services, 
From [Microsoft : How to: Debug Windows Service Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/how-to-debug-windows-service-applications)

-Add a method to your service that runs the OnStart and OnStop methods:

```
internal void TestStartupAndStop(string[] args)  
{  
    this.OnStart(args);  
    Console.ReadLine();  
    this.OnStop();  
}
```

-Rewrite the Main method as follows:

```
static void Main(string[] args)  
{  
    if (Environment.UserInteractive)  
    {  
        MyNewService service1 = new MyNewService(args);  
        service1.TestStartupAndStop(args);  
    }  
    else  
    {  
        // Put the body of your old Main method here.  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of the question you are getting the error when trying to run in debug locally.

You need to run the service differently when running locally in debug mode compared to installed release mode, the code below is what I use:

```
static void Main()
{
#if !DEBUG

    ServiceBase[] servicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
    {
        new Scheduler()
    };

    ServiceBase.Run(servicesToRun);

#else

    Scheduler service = new Scheduler();
    service.ScheduleService();

    Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);

#endif
}
```